# List of Coprimes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Is there a way to generate a list of parametrized length, say $L$, of integers which are relatively prime among them? I would like to take into account their word-length as well, so for example the list would contain only 32-bit numbers.

Comment: `Prime@Range[L]` will have that property. It feels as if you had omitted something important from the question ... which would explain why `Prime@Range[L]` is not what you want ...

Comment: You can also use `RandomPrime` if you want big numbers.

Comment: I wouldn't like to have only prime numbers, but rather a list of relatively prime numbers. I tried though your command and I get something weird: `Prime@Range[2^31, 2^31 + 22]` outputs numbers that are larger than $2^{31}+22$. Any idea why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a list of mutually coprime integers? The function `CoprimeSet[n,m]` finds sets of `m` mutually coprime integers from the first `n>m` integers.

```
CoprimeSet[n_, m_] := Pick[#, CoprimeQ @@@ #] &[Subsets[Range[n], {m}]]
```

For example,

```
CoprimeSet[8,5]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 5, 7}, {1, 3, 4, 5, 7}, {1, 3, 5, 7, 8}}

Alternatively, `CoprimeSetRandom[n,m,kmin,kmax]` finds sets of `m` mutually coprime integers from a random selection of `n` integers between `kmin` and `kmax`.

```
CoprimeRandomSet[n_, m_, kmin_, kmax_] := 
    Pick[#, CoprimeQ @@@ #] &[Subsets[RandomInteger[{kmin, kmax}, n], {m}]]
```

For example,

```
CoprimeRandomSet[10, 5, 1800, 2000]
```

> {{1803, 1888, 1811, 1961, 1951}, {1803, 1930, 1811, 1961, 1951}}

Comment: Nice effort thanks, although I can't seem to make it work for 32-bit numbers. I tried for example `CoprimeRandomSet[50, 22, 2^32, 2^32-1]` but I got a message for insufficient memory (16GB + 16GB swap in Ubuntu)

Comment: You have asked for subsets of 22 integers from a list of 50 integers, which is a list of billions of sublists. So memory will always be insufficient for such large cases. Assuming you reduce n and m, you must have kmin less than kmax, whereas your example in the comment has kmax less than kmin.

Comment: Correct, that was a typo. I used `CoprimeRandomSet[22,22,2^31,2^32-1]` to get just 1 set of 22 coprime numbers but I got no output.